# connect hybrid android app with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, hybrid-mobile-app

i have a hybrid android app built with html5,javascript and jquery . and I want to connect this app with mysql database ! , i've search but i didn't find a good method to do it.

Please if you have any tutorials or method .

Answer (score 2):

I can say easiest way is to build some kind of REST layer for communicating the database, this also means you have to add something server side also (PHP, java, Node.js or something else)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2325799 - Android Client-Server Communication (PHP-MYSQL REST API)

Comment: thank you for that tutorial , but i have another question, now it seems that i must use java and xml for button .. so my app will change from a hybrid app to native one , i'll not be able to work with html5 and css, javascript ...?

Comment: Well if you use native approach then the application communication with server remains same you can use REST. Only the client side changes, you have to use android HTTP library to make requests.